# Taking difference of two dataframe while keeping values from first if it doesnt exist in second

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I have 2 dataframes:
Dataframe `Current` is as follows:

```
Type1   Type2   Val1    Val2
A       a       73      86
B       s       8       17
D       d       33      41
```

Dataframe `Target` is as follows:

```
Type1   Type2   Val1    Val2
A       a       159     199
B       s       135     198
C       f       200     145
D       d       149     119
```

I want to find the difference of `Target - Current` to get the following:

```
Type1   Type2   Val1    Val2
A       a       86      113
B       s       127     181
C       f       200     145
D       d       116     78
```

All `Type1, Type2` pair in `Current` is present in `Target` but vice versa is not true. I am not sure how to approach the above.

`159 - 73 = 86` for `Type 1 = A and Type 2 = a` but `Type 1 = C and Type 2 = f` is not present in `Current` so it is basically 0 for `Current` dataframe. Hence, `Target - Currnet` is set to values of `Target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set_index` to set a `MultiLevel` index in both the `target` and `current` dataframe as `Type1` and `Type2`, then use [`DataFrame.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) with optional parameter `fill_value=0` (to keep the values from `first` if it doesn't exist in `second`):

```
diff = (
    target.set_index(['Type1', 'Type2'])
    .sub(current.set_index(['Type1', 'Type2']), fill_value=0).reset_index()
)
```

Result:

```
print(diff)
  Type1 Type2   Val1   Val2
0     A     a   86.0  113.0
1     B     s  127.0  181.0
2     C     f  200.0  145.0
3     D     d  116.0   78.0
```

Comment: What is the significance of "()" that you have used to wrap your logic part of code?

Comment: `()` is used so that we can wrap  the code in multiple lines or in other word our chained functions can span into mulitple lines for better readibility.

Comment: This is first time that I am seeing this .. in my Current dataframe Type2 column name is something different. Using your code, it stacks up the dataframes. I never had this kind of problem as I thought once you set index, it doesn't matter what column name originally was.